# PowerShell get weekday name from a date

Tags: powershell

Using powershell I want to get the week day name (Friday) from a date.  Been googling and cant find this one.  It so I can do an IF statement to do something if the date is a Friday.

Can anyone help?

Comment: (Get-Date "15/01/2016").DayOfWeek

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Get-Date` to produce a DateTime object, then call its DayOfWeek method. For example:

```
(get-date 01/01/2016).DayOfWeek
```